# Unknown URI Error in insertImage

Tags: android, mediastore

Trying saving bitmap into gallery

```
Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(surfaceView.getWidth(), surfaceView.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
surfaceView.draw(new Canvas(bitmap));
MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), bitmap, "foo" , "bar");
```

I ran the application on the emulator and got an UnsupportedOperationException.

```
07-25 22:27:48.719: E/MediaStore(1918): Failed to insert image
07-25 22:27:48.719: E/MediaStore(1918): java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown URI: content://media/external/images/media
07-25 22:27:48.719: E/MediaStore(1918):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:168)
07-25 22:27:48.719: E/MediaStore(1918):     at android.database.DatabaseUtils.readExceptionFromParcel(DatabaseUtils.java:136)
07-25 22:27:48.719: E/MediaStore(1918):     at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.insert(ContentProviderNative.java:415)
07-25 22:27:48.719: E/MediaStore(1918):     at android.content.ContentResolver.insert(ContentResolver.java:730)
07-25 22:27:48.719: E/MediaStore(1918):     at android.provider.MediaStore$Images$Media.insertImage(MediaStore.java:801)
```

Unfortunately I don't have any android device right now, is this because of the emulator? Or another reason?

Answer (score 4):

I have had similar problems when the directory DCIM/Camera didn't exist on the sdcard. Creating the directory (and having the permission) has resolved a similar problem for me.

Answer (score 3):

I found that it was an emulator problem.  I had not set up the emulator correctly.  To fix this what I did was to open the android Virtual device manager, edit the AVD and add a SD Card size.  Once I have done that I start the AVD and take a picture.  After I have done that, it started working.