# Setting mp3 as Ringtone Error on Button Hit

Tags: java, android, audio

I am trying to build an Andorid application that sets an .mp3 file as a ringtone, notification or alarm. After searching google I came across an example that worked for a bunch of different people. When running the application I get an Error message that the app stopped working and `LogCat` spits this out

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unknown URI: content://media//storage/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/joytotheworld_symphony.mp3/audio/media"
```

I did some debugging and I noticed that the error came from

```
Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(k.getAbsolutePath());
```

**Here is the rest of the code for the object that sets the ringtone/notification/alarm:**

```
    public boolean saveas(int type) {
    byte[] buffer = null;
    String filename = null;
    InputStream fIn = getBaseContext().getResources().openRawResource(
            R.raw.joytotheworld_symphony);
    int size = 0;
    String collected = null;
    try {
        size = fIn.available();
        buffer = new byte[size];
        while(fIn.read(buffer) != -1){
            collected = new String(buffer);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }finally{
        try {
            fIn.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    String path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
            + "/media/audio/ringtones/";
    filename = "joytotheworld_symphony" + ".mp3";

    boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
    if (!exists) {
        new File(path).mkdirs();
    }

    FileOutputStream save;
    try {
        save = new FileOutputStream(path + filename);
        save.write(buffer);
        save.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        return false;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }

    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE,
            Uri.parse("file://" + path + filename)));
    File k = new File(path, filename);

    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, filename);
    values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");

    // This method allows to change Notification and Alarm tone also. Just
    // pass corresponding type as parameter
    if (RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE == type) {
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
    } else if (RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION == type) {
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
    } else if (RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM == type) {
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
    }

    Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUri(k.getAbsolutePath());
    Uri newUri = Set.this.getContentResolver().insert(uri, values);
    try{
        RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(Set.this, type, newUri);
    }catch (Throwable t){
        Log.d("mn", "catch exception");
    }

    // Insert it into the database
    this.getContentResolver()
            .insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k
                    .getAbsolutePath()), values);

    return true;
}
```

I have no idea how to fix this, I tried searching online and I just couldn't find a fix (it could be that I just didn't search in the right place).

Is there anyone that can help me out please.

Thanks in advance,

Maza.

Edit: I forgot to mention that I have also written the permission that was needed in the manifest and the AVD does have an SD set up with 500 Mb of space

Comment: Check out [this question/answers][1]...


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17860526/unknown-uri-error-in-insertimage

Comment: @nadavfima I have tried what was suggested in the post you linked and still no luck. I have also built 3 different emulators on which I ran the application on with the same error result.

Comment: I have Fixed the Issue with code from here: [solved](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314727/setting-a-custom-ringtone-produces-filenotfound-exception?rq=1)   The problem was that I used '.getContentUri(k.getAbsolutePath())' when I needed to use '.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath())'